# Dynamic Programming- Primitive Calculator

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The full explanation of the problem is here---https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CWF1.jpg .
I've written the code, but it is showing segmentation error which I'm not able to solve. As per the logic of the program, I am saving the minimum number of operations needed to reach number n on the nth position of the array. I intend to go by this logic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long f(long long n, vector <long long> arr)
{ 
    arr[1]=0;

    arr.push_back(n);
    long long ans=0, ret=0;

    if (n==1)
    {
        return (0);
    }
    ans= f(n-1, arr) + 1;


    if (n%2==0)
    {
        ret= f(n/2, arr) + 1;
        if (ret<ans)
        {
            ans=ret;
            std::cout<<ans<<'\n';
        }
    }
    if (n%3==0)
    { 
        ret= f(n/3, arr) + 1;
        if (ret<ans)
        {
            ans=ret;
            std::cout<<ans<<'\n';
        }
    }
    arr[n]=ans;

    return arr[n];    
}

int main() {

    long long n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<long long> arr;
    std::cout<<f(n, arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two hints: Array (and vector) indexes start at *zero*. And a vector starts out *empty* meaning any indexing in it will be *out of bounds* and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Please do not put problem description in a picture or behind a link. Prefix the paragraph by symbol '>' and simply write it down here. Also, the programmer dude basically gave you the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long long f(long long n, vector <long long> arr)
{ 
    arr[1]=0;

    //arr.push_back(n);       // not required
    long long ans=0, ret=0;

    if (n==1)
    {
        return (0);
    }
    ans= f(n-1, arr) + 1;


    if (n%2==0)
    {
        ret= f(n/2, arr) + 1;
        if (ret<ans)
        {
            ans=ret;
            //std::cout<<ans<<'\n';
        }
    }
    if (n%3==0)
    { 
        ret= f(n/3, arr) + 1;
        if (ret<ans)
        {
            ans=ret;
            //std::cout<<ans<<'\n';
        }
    }
    arr[n]=ans;

    return arr[n];    
}

int main() {

    long long n = 120;
    std::vector<long long> arr(n+1);     // declare arr with size n+1 
    std::cout<<f(n, arr);

    return 0;
}
```

You have accessed a[1] without declaring size of array >= 2 as array in c++ is 0 indexing and in addition to that if you provide array with some initial size as `arr(n+1)` while declaring then no need to push value of n in `arr` again.

then your solution works correct.

for itterative approach

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    long long n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<long long> arr(n+1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + 1;
        if (i % 2 == 0) arr[i] = min(1 + arr[i / 2], arr[i]);
        if (i % 3 == 0) arr[i] = min(1 + arr[i / 3], arr[i]);
    }
    cout << arr[n]-1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```